# Is there a way to check duplicated connection in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, duplicates, signals-slots

If a

```
connect(sender,signal,receiver,slot);
```

is called multiple times. When the signal is emit the slot will be called multiple times. I know UniqueConnection can be used to prevent this.

But is there a way to quickly check the potential duplicated connection?
I am now looking into a project with thousands of lines of codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Conan](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Conan+-+Connection+analyzer+for+Qt?content=108330) which is a connection analyzer for Qt. Using it you can see object
hierarchies, object inheritance, signal/slot connections, and signal emissions at run time. It claims that :

> Conan has been used to identify multiple duplicate connections in the
>   source code of Qt!

An other option is to use [GammaRay](http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/gammaray/) which is a perfect tool to analyze your Qt application in many aspects. Of course it has the ability of browsing object properties, signals, slots and connections.